# Returning pointer to static local variable

Tags: c, static, declaration

When I compile this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *foo();

int main()
{
        *foo()++;
        return 0;
}

int *foo()
{
        static int bar;
        return &bar;
}
```

Clang shows me an error:

```
static2.c:7:8: error: expression is not assignable
```

Why it's illegal? I suppose `bar` have static storage duration, so its lifetime is **the entire execution of the program**. Although `bar` itself isn't visible to `main()`, a pointer should be able to modify it.

This version of `foo()` doesn't work too, and Clang gives me the same error:

```
int *foo()
{
    static int bar;
    static int* ptr = &bar;
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to operator precedence (suffix increment, `++`, is higher than dereference, `*`) (See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence),

```
    *foo()++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
    *(foo()++);
```

That is invalid since the return value of `foo` is a pointer and `foo()` evaluates to a temporary pointer. You cannot increment or decrement a temporary pointer.

You can fix it by using:

```
    (*foo())++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Its illegal because of the way you are using the return value. `bar` is visible and can be used in `main()`

The problem is with

```
*foo()++;
```

You need to provide the expression in parentheses

```
(*(foo()))++;
```